# Cannot parse date with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, parsing, date

I get an `Invalid date` exception when I try to parse the following date with jQuery UI datepicker's [parseDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-parseDate) utility function:

```
$.datepicker.parseDate("ddmy", "10982");
```

I'm using jQuery 1.8.0. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation it seems like jQuery can't parse a date with a single digit for days or months (although I still think this should be possible according to the docs).

I'm now using a workaround where I pad the user entered string, before I feed it to jQuery's parse function:

```
var text = ...
if (text.length === 4) { // dmyy
  text = "0" + text.substring(0, 1) + "0" + text.substring(1);
} else if (text.length === 5) { // ddmyy 
  text = text.substring(0, 2) + "0" + text.substring(2);
}
$.datepicker.parseDate("ddmmyy", text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done some testing and figure out that, the format is Ok but the Value it can not parse,

so i have tried with below code:

```
$.datepicker.parseDate("ddmy", "100982");
```

it means each format will required 2 character lenth(like 2 digit for Day,2 digit for Month and same for the Year)

Hope you have got your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know, *sigh*. `100982` parses ok. But I rather would allow users to enter `10982` as well. Would be a shame, if this cannot be done with jQuery's parsing function. I fear you're right, though... ;(

Answer (score 0):

Your instruction gives invalid date error, you'd better use this more detailed format:

```
$.datepicker.parseDate("ddmmyy", "10091982");
```

Ref. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ .

Comment: I'm actually trying to guess what a user has entered. `ddmy` is one of the formats I'm trying to guess if a valid date was entered. According to the jQuery docs `ddmy` should parse `10982` alright...

Comment: ddmy appearantly disappeared in jQuery 1.8, and in my case jQuery 1.10?

Comment: What do you mean by "disappeared"?